# Is this even possible? sending email with RoR with different FROM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building an application using Ruby on Rails. I want to do something that I am not even sure is possible;

I have a mailer that is working, however I want to enable users to send emails using their own email address in the FROM parameter. Its almost as if the ":from" parameter has no effect on the email sent.

I'm a bit of a noob when dealing with email servers so please be as detailed as possible. I doubt there is a smtp mail server set up on my hosting account, so if I need to do something like install smtp on my hosting account please be as descriptive as possible.

Comment: Are you using gmail as your smtp server?

Comment: I am using gmail. I'm not surprised that they would limit what the FROM is, but if there is another way I need more direction on how to do it. This is way out of my area of expertise.

Comment: You'd either need to find a server that allows you to spoof e-mails (still, though, you may run into spam issues), or have your users enter their e-mail account details and dynamically switch smtp servers based on the user. @tadman's answer is probably best, though.

Comment: Gmail will let you use a different From address -- if you register it as an alternate e-mail address on your Google account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are able to set the `From:` field to whatever you want, theoretically, but in practice you are often limited as to what you can put in there. Many email providers will automatically replace the From address with your own regardless so that you can't masquerade as someone else.

You're probably intending to do something like this:

```
From: Example Customer Name <name@example.com>
```

Also keep in mind that sending email from arbitrary domains will result in a very high chance of being flagged as spam since you are most likely not listed as as a host authorized to send for those domains which is typically implemented with [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework).

The best practice is to set the address to be something like this:

```
From: Example Customer Name <you@yourdomain.name>
```

That way you're not spoofing your actual email address, only the associated label, which is not typically verified.

Comment: You can also set a custom Reply-To header that will go to the user's e-mail.

Comment: thanks tadman - I guess for the time being this is acceptable, although it might become an issue down the road, if customers click respond to the email sent by an account/user. I was hoping someone might have some direction if/when the time comes to pull this off without asking for users to provide their email user id/password.

Comment: thanks Dylan - that might work, the reply-to. I have no idea how to do that but I suspect there is good information in the web somewhere.

Comment: In your mailer, just set the `:reply_to` option in your `mail(...)` call. Keep in mind though that some e-mail clients will ignore the reply-to...

Comment: so here is my follow up questions - is this even possible? If so then how? and are you saying that even it is possible I shouldn't do it because of potential issues related to spam on the "to" param for the emails?

Comment: Set the `From` to something that's your email address, but labelled as the user's name, set the `Reply-To` to the user's email, just as suggested. Why are you asking about the `To` header?

Comment: I mean if I send the email to someone by spoofing the user's email address will the mail server of the "to" param (i.e. gmail) classify the email as spam?